# how to create menus with permissions yii

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

Could anyone tell me if it is possible and how to display the menu items in accordance with the permissions registered with the Rights in Yii framework?

Comment: There is no single way to achieve that. One way could be to set menu item visibility based on user roles. For instance, `'visible' => Yii::app()->user->hasRole('menuRole');`. Where `'visible'` is defined in menu item array.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I managed to accomplish this mission, but I appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

OBS.:I use Google Translate to translate my questions, so if there are any errors in the writing, I'm sorry, I'm from Brazil.